I keep getting errors with my machine learning model
It's just a version of a model i made which predicts stocks, when I run it, it works fine, but returns errors with the output, note indentations were messed up but its self explanatory
This is the code:
import yfinance as yf
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

start_date = "2000-01-01"
end_date = None
model = LinearRegression()
tickers = ("AMZN","AAPL","TSLA")

for stock_symbol in tickers:
stock_data = yf.download(tickers = stock_symbol, start=start_date, end=end_date, interval = "1d")
model.fit(stock_data[['Open', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']], stock_data['High'])

today_data = yf.download(stock_symbol, period="1d", interval="1d")
today_features = today_data[['Open', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']]
predicted_high_tomorrow = model.predict(today_features)

if float(predicted_high_tomorrow) > float(today_data["High"]):
status = "BUY"
else:
status = "SELL"

today_high = today_data["High"]
print(f"{stock_symbol}  {today_high}    {predicted_high_tomorrow}   {status}")

It returns the correct output, aswell as some errors:
DeprecationWarning: Conversion of an array with ndim > 0 to a scalar is deprecated
FutureWarning: Calling float on a single element Series is deprecated and will raise a TypeError in the future.


Warnings are not errors, do you have actual error messages?

Please fix the indentation, no matter how obvious you may think the correct indentation is.

Although warnings are not errors and they don't affect the results, it means that you cannot directly convert an array to a float in this step if float(predicted_high_tomorrow) > float(today_data["High"]):. Instead, You need to convert the array to a scalar value. For example if predicted_high_tomorrow[0] > today_data["High"].values[0]:
